# how to read text file and store data in to the array list

Tags: c#

This is my problem.i have text file it's contain no of animals names Inside of my text file is like this.

cat 
dog
rat
elephant
bird

now i want to read this text file and store these content in to the array list
i'm try to the several method  for solve these problem but its not word....

these is my code

```
List<String> arrayList = new List<String>(); 

String path = Server.MapPath("~\\Resarch\\new.txt");
StreamReader sre = new StreamReader(path); 

for (int x = 0; x < arrayList.Count; x++)
{
     arrayList[x] = sre.ReadLine();     
}  

foreach(var a in arrayList)
{
    TextBox1.Text = a;
}
```

Comment: You want `File.ReadAllLines("~\\Resarch\\new.txt")`.

Comment: Do you want to display content of text file on your textbox ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `File.ReadAllLines`

```
var arrayList = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).ToList();
```

One more point, you are looping through collection and assigning *last* value in the collection to `Textbox` is this expected? Do you need all values to display in textbox or just the last value?

**Update :**
Display List values in the `Textbox`

```
TextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, arrayList);
```

Comment: no my file reading part is ok ..actually i want to store data in to the arraylits and retrieve that data

Comment: Do you want to display that text in `TextBox` ?

Comment: i want display  all value in the textbox

Comment: no noting display any thing..not error 
not i edit my code like these now generate erro "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is old, but I think my answer will help other users.
If you want to get some data from a text file, you can use this line of code:

```
var data = File.ReadAllLines("text.txt").Select(x => x.Split('=')).Where(x => x.Length > 1).ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);
```

This is how your `text.txt` file should look like to get that work:

```
Animal1=cat
Animal2=dog
Animal3=rat
Animal4=elephant
Animal5=bird
```

The general usage of this code will be:

```
string a = string.Format("Animal: {0}", data["Animal"]);
```

For instance, if I understood it right, you already know your numbers of animals.
So you can do a `for` loop from 1 to the last animal number:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
            string animal = string.Format("Animal{0}: {1}", i, data["Animal" + i]);
            // The command to insert data to the array needs to come here.
}
```